# Update content dynamically in Django admin

Tags: django

I have a django admin dashboard where I can add animations. For each animation I first need to select, in a drop down menu, the animation type, for example 'Background'. I would like to display a specific field when 'Background' is selected. Now if I select select 'GOAL' type a different field must appears etc...

I started like this trying to change the default value of the Charfield but no success for the moment...

```
class Sequence(models.Model):

BACKGROUND = 'BACKGROUND'
SEQUENCE = 'PRODUCT'
INTROLOOP = 'INTROLOOP'
GOAL = 'GOAL'
FOREGROUND = 'FOREGROUND'
TEST = ''

ANIMATION_TYPE = (
    (BACKGROUND, 'BACKGROUND'),
    (SEQUENCE, 'PRODUCT'),
    (INTROLOOP, 'INTROLOOP'),
    (GOAL, 'GOAL'),
    (FOREGROUND, 'FOREGROUND'),
)

titre_CmdiLayer = models.CharField(max_length=5,
                                  choices=ANIMATION_TYPE,
                                  default=BACKGROUND)

if titre_CmdiLayer.NEED_TO_GET_THE_VALUE_OF_THE_CHARFIELD == 'BACKGROUND' :
    TEST = 'BACKGROUND'
else :
    TEST = 'SOMETHINGELSE'

titre_sequence = models.CharField('Name', max_length=50, default=TEST, unique=True)
pub_date_sequence = models.DateTimeField('Date & Time')
def __str__ (self):
    return self.titre_sequence
```

If someone has an idea? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to do here. There's many kinds of custom UI that is not really suited for the django admin, and which is better implemented as regular django views. For rich interaction, you typically also have to use javascript.

Comment: Can you make some sort of graphic or mockup to explain the interaction you want? Or a screenshot and or link to some existing site that does this.